# call custom functions from Add-ons menu in Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, menu, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I've developed a collection of functions that are to be used by our Desktop and Service Desk team and have deployed a custom powershell ISE profile to each staff member that loads the module file that contains all of the functions.

I've been asked to make them more user friendly, so my next logical thought was to create a custom menu within PSISE under the Add-ons menu item.

Knowing that I will continually add new functions to the module file, I dont want to hardcode any menu items - I want the menu items to reflect exactly what functions exist or are available at the time the profile is loaded.

My first thought was to create a list of the current functions once loaded and then loop through each function and add an item to the add-ons menu as shown below.

```psh
env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";\\remotelocation\Modules"
$CommandList = Get-Command -Module "CompanyModules" | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Name

function Add-ISEMenuItem([String]$MenuName,[String]$Name,[ScriptBlock]$Script,[String]$Shortcut) 
{
    try{
         if ( $Shortcut ) { $Menus[$MenuName].Submenus.Add($Name, $Script, $Shortcut) | Out-Null }
        else { $Menus[$MenuName].Submenus.Add($Name, $Script,$null) | Out-Null }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}

function Add-ISESubMenu([String]$MenuName,[String]$Name) 
{
    try
    {
        if (-not ($menus -contains $MenuName))
        {
            $menus[$Name] = $menus[$MenuName].SubMenus.Add($Name,$null,$null)
        }
        else
        {
            throw "Menu name already used"
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}    

##############################################################################
# Setting up the PowerShell_ISE environment
#############################################################################

$menus = @{}
$menus["AddOns"] = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu

Add-ISESubMenu -MenuName "AddOns" -Name "Company Modules"

$count = $CommandList.count

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++)
{
    $cmd = $CommandList[$i]
    Add-ISEMenuItem -MenuName "Company Modules" -Name "$cmd" -Script { $cmd[0] }
}
```

All good so far, when the profile is loaded, a submenu is created named "Company Modules" and each function is displayed within that menu - however when the function is selected, instead of running the function, it simply expands the value of $cmd which is always just the String value of the first function name.

I understand this is due to the -Script value and its requirement to have its value contained in curly braces.. but I can't for the life of me figure out how to overcome this.

Is there any way at all to have the functions run from the add-ons menu exactly as if you had typed them into the console manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```psh
$CommandList = Get-Command -Module "CompanyModules" | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Name
```

What you've done here is you've only gotten the name of each function in `$CommandList`.

So instead let's change it to this:

```psh
$CommandList = Get-Command -Module "CompanyModules"
```

to get the entire command object.

Then at the bottom of the script:

```psh
$CommandList | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ISEMenuItem -MenuName "Company Modules" -Name $_.Name -Script ([ScriptBlock]::Create($_.Definition))
}
```

Note that you can still use your `for` loop to iterate the `$CommandList` if you want to, I just think this is easier.

The `.Definition` property on a function returned by `Get-Command` contains a `[String]` of the code that makes up the function. You cna turn that into a ScriptBlock by using `[ScriptBlock]::Create()`.

What you were doing before was basically just passing a new scriptblock that printed out just the name of the function.

Comment: Thanks @briantist
Makes a lot of sense - I've really got to remember how valuable get-member really is!

One last thing - the code is definitely executed, but is there any way to suppress the function definition being dumped to the screen?

Comment: I'm not certain but I would guess no. It's the same behavior as when you execute a file that isn't saved, so I imagine it's handling it internally the same way.